# Nesting big-O with big-Omega $O(g(\Omega(h(n))))$: is it $O$ for all $\Omega$ or for one $\Omega$?

Tags: computational-complexity, terminology, asymptotics, notation

I want to express the following statement about a function $f(n)$: there exists $f_\Omega\in\Omega(h(n))$ such that $f\in O(g(f_\Omega(n))$. What's the correct notation for this? Is it $f\in O(g(\Omega(h(n))))$? Or does that notation mean that $f\in O(g(f_\Omega(n))$ for ***all*** $f_\Omega\in\Omega(h(n))$?

For example, take $f(n)=2^{-\alpha n}(n^4+n^2+\log(n))$ for $\alpha>0$. Such a function has that there exists $f_\Omega\in\Omega(n)$ (take $f_\Omega(n)=\alpha n/2$ for example) such that $f\in O(2^{-f_\Omega(n)})$. I want a nice succinct way to say this that stresses the important part (the exponential) and without mentioning the constant $\alpha$ as it is subject to change. I was thinking that this does it: $2^{-5n}(n^4+n^2+\log(n))\in O(2^{-\Omega(n)})$. But I'm not sure if this is "there exists $f_\Omega$" or "for all $f_\Omega$" (which would mean $f$ is eventually zero?) and if it's the latter then what's the right way of writing this?

Comment: In your example, just $f(n)=2^{-\Omega(n)}$ is fine. There is no need for the outer $O$, and while people abuse asymptotic notations in all kinds of ways as long as the intended meaning is reasonably clear, I can’t remember seeing two of them nested like this.

Comment: Having said that, I would interpret $f\in O(g(\Omega(h(n))))$ the way you want, on the principle that if $X$ is a set of functions in one variable (like $\Omega(h)$), then $g(X)$ can stand for $\{g\circ g':g'\in X\}$.

Comment: I'd like point to [this paper](people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf) that discusses the ambiguities in big-O notation for functions of multiple variables. The relevant part of it is the discussion of the desired properties of big-O notation. In particular, neither "exist" not "all" interpretation correspond to our intuition of what big-O should mean for functions of multiple variables. Although this is not the answer to your question perhaps the consideration involved in choosing the meaning of big-O notation would be useful.

Comment: I read Howell’s paper, and while I agree that it wouldn’t hurt if people were more careful and explicit when using asymptotic notation for multivariate functions, I couldn’t help the feeling he’s trying to be intentionally obtuse. There is a perfectly natural meaning one can give to $g(n,m)=O(f(n,m))$ for positive integer functions $f,g$, namely that there exists a constant $c$ such that $g(n,m)\le cf(n,m)$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$. This agrees with the univariate case, and generally fits the expectation of those who employ such notation, though it violates Howell’s conditions.

Comment: My view is that asymptotic notation such as $O()$ or $\Omega()$ is basically a more sophisticated version of more familiar multi-valued notations, such as $\pm$, with $f(n) = O( g( \Omega( h(n) ) )$ being interpreted much like $x = \pm  g(\pm y)$ would, namely that there exists a choice of both signs which makes the identity valid.  (Ignore for the moment the fact that one does often want to force the $\pm$ signs to agree (and for $\mp$ to denote the opposite sign), but this is not the default convention and usually has to be stated explicitly.)

Comment: A good rule of thumb though is that potentially ambiguous notation can be OK if all the other potential interpretations of the intended notation are either clearly inappropriate for the context, or equivalent to the intended interpretation.  In particular, the function $g$ is monotone decreasing then there looks like there is little chance of ambiguity and the notation looks reasonably safe to me, but if $g$ is oscillatory then this notation should probably be avoided.

Comment: *There exists $f_\Omega\in\Omega(h(n))$ such that $f\in O(g(f_\Omega(n))$.* This is clear, easy to understand, and relatively concise. I think it should be preferred to some more confusing or difficult-to-parse notation, even granting (the apparently non-obvious fact) that the latter is technically correct and not ambiguous.